# Stubbing objects drawn from the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, mocha.js, minitest

Rails 4.2 testing with Minitest and Mocha

I want to keep my unit test within the model it's testing - not testing functionality done by another model. The model `has_many :language_progresses` and I'm trying to test a method that takes a subset of those `language_progresses` and sums the output of a method called on them like this:

```
def outcome_month_score(outcome_area, year = Date.today.year, month = Date.today.month)
  lps = language_progresses.includes(:progress_marker).
    where("progress_markers.topic_id" => outcome_area.id)
  lps.inject(0){ |sum, lp| sum + lp.month_score(year, month) }
end
```

here's my test:

```
it "must calculate the outcome score for an outcome area in a month" do
  year = 2015
  month = 1
  pm1 = progress_markers(:skills_used)
  pm2 = progress_markers(:new_initiatives)
  pm_other = progress_markers(:devotional)
  lp1 = LanguageProgress.new progress_marker: pm1
  lp2 = LanguageProgress.new progress_marker: pm2
  lp_other = LanguageProgress.new progress_marker: pm_other
  lp1.stubs(:month_score).with(year, month).returns(1)
  lp2.stubs(:month_score).with(year, month).returns(2)
  lp_other.stubs(:month_score).with(year, month).returns(4)
  state_language.language_progresses << [lp1, lp2, lp_other]
  state_language.save
  _(state_language.outcome_month_score(topics(:social_development), year, month)).must_equal 3
end
```

My problem is that the stubs stop working before their outputs are summed in the method. They all return 0, even though I checked they work fine in  the test just after they are made.

I think when the language_progresses are loaded from the db the stubs are cancelled out.

How should I test this method?

Answer (score 2):

Your guess is correct -- the use of ActiveRecord's query interface instantiates new LanguageProgress instances and ignores your stub on the relation.

In general, for a method like this -- which makes use of a non-trivial query expression -- I would not try to test it in isolation. The method is most likely to break by altering the SQL query to something invalid, and any level of unit testing you write would have to stub out the query methods such that you lose any guarantee the query it's running is actually valid SQL.

In your case, though, it might be difficult to create fully-valid language progresses and be able to reason about their month scores. I suggest you isolate the two parts of the method: the retrieval, which involves SQL and really can't be **truly** unit-tested, and the computation, which is easy to unit-test.

```
def progresses_for_area(outcome_area)
  language_progresses.includes(:progress_marker).
    where("progress_markers.topic_id" => outcome_area.id)
end

def outcome_month_score(outcome_area, year = Date.today.year, month = Date.today.month)
  progresses_for_area(outcome_area).inject(0){ |sum, lp| sum + lp.month_score(year, month) }
  # or:
  # progresses_for_area(outcome_area).map { |lp| lp.month_score(year, month) }.sum
end
```

Then your test would be:

```
it "must calculate the outcome score for an outcome area in a month" do
  year = 2015
  month = 1

  pm1 = progress_markers(:skills_used)
  pm2 = progress_markers(:new_initiatives)
  lp1 = LanguageProgress.new progress_marker: pm1
  lp2 = LanguageProgress.new progress_marker: pm2
  lp1.stubs(:month_score).with(year, month).returns(1)
  lp2.stubs(:month_score).with(year, month).returns(2)

  state_language.stubs(:progresses_for_area).returns([lp1, lp2])

  _(state_language.outcome_month_score(topics(:social_development), year, month)).must_equal 3
end
```

And you could write a separate test to verify that `progresses_for_area` works, which would be easier as you don't need to calculate any month_scores.

Comment: nice answer, and I'd probably make it the accepted one if In hadn't recently read an article railing against test-driven development saying how we add unneeded complexity to code in order to make it easier to test. I'm not against TDD, but I think there's something in what he says, and this answer may be an example of that.

Comment: I'd say my refactoring of your model is actually better code, and the improved testability is just a symptom of that. Between your answer and mine, I know which model and test I'd rather maintain...

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to do it is to stub two methods in the collection `state_languages.language_progresses`. The two methods are `includes` and `where`. Doing this will prevent ActiveRecord from retrieving the LanguageProgress objects from the database. Thus:

```
it "must calculate the outcome score for an outcome area in a month" do
  year = 2015
  month = 1
  pm1 = progress_markers(:skills_used)
  pm2 = progress_markers(:new_initiatives)
  pm_other = progress_markers(:devotional)
  lp1 = LanguageProgress.new progress_marker: pm1
  lp2 = LanguageProgress.new progress_marker: pm2
  lp_other = LanguageProgress.new progress_marker: pm_other
  lp1.stubs(:month_score).with(year, month).returns(1)
  lp2.stubs(:month_score).with(year, month).returns(2)
  lp_other.stubs(:month_score).with(year, month).returns(4)
  state_language.language_progresses << [lp1, lp2, lp_other]
  state_language.language_progresses.stubs(:includes).returns state_language.language_progresses
  state_language.language_progresses.
    stubs(:where).
    with("progress_markers.topic_id" => topics(:social_development).id).
    returns state_language.language_progresses.select{ |lp|
      lp.progress_marker.topic.id == topics(:social_development).id
    }
  _(state_language.outcome_month_score(topics(:social_development), year, month)).must_equal 3
end
```

here I've made the `includes` method simply return the `language_progresses` collection and the `where` method returns a subset of that collection.

The disadvantage of this is that we don't test that the query in the method we're testing returns the right records - if it didn't the test would still pass, but the real method would give the wrong output. That is why I've also specified the parameter for the `where` stub. That way I can be reasonably sure that with that parameter the selection of `LanguageProgress`es I make in the test matches the one in the real method produced by where. If the parameter changes in the method under test then the test would stop passing. It's not foolproof, but I think it's close enough.